# SQL compare records in multiple rows in same table

Tags: sql, select

I have table with: Port_nbr, Pair, length, add_date.
example:

```
port_nbr        | 4
pair            | pairC
length          | 33.12
add_date        | 2020-06-16 00:01:13.237164
```

There is 4 pairs intotal ( A,B,C,D) and each port_nbr has a pair(A-D) atleast once. It means, each port_nbr can be multiple times. I need to find out if that port any pair length is increased by 30m. To do it, i must order each port_nbr by date, because i need to compare 1 record with next record and find out when it increased by 30m

example:
RECORD 1

```
port_nbr | 1                          
pair     | pairA
length   | 30.00
add_date | 2020-06-16 00:01:13.237164
```

RECRORD 2

```
port_nbr | 1                              
pair     | pairA
length   | 65.00
add_date | 2020-06-16 00:02:13.237164
```

expected output- Length increased on: port 1, pairA, 2020-06-16 00:02:13.237164 by 35m

There is hundreds of records and i have to compare one to another record, but it has to be same port and pair.

Everything i have right now is:

```
Select *
from diags a join
     (SELECT port_nbr, count(*) from diags group by port_nbr having count(*) > 1 ) b
     on a.port_nbr = b.port_nbr
order by a.port_nbr
```

It would help a lot if someone could explain what i should to try add to get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `lead()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             lead(length) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by add_date) as next_length
      from diags d
     ) d
where next_length > length + 30;
```

This gets the next length for the same part/pair combo and returns rows where the next value exceeds your threshold.

Comment: I think this should work, but i forgot 1 important thing... Length is a character varying. It means i need to change data type to float  ( because numbers can be decimals) and also some values are N/A, it means i need to include ```length != 'N/A'``` But i dont know how to include it to your code... Also i know that i can change data type with ```length::float``` I just dont know where do i place it. Error - operator does not exist: character varying + integer

Comment: @Cris . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and -- importantly -- a database tag.

Comment: Im working  with groovy and psql. I have database with 1 table where is hundreds of records. There is many different ports (port_nbr). Each port have atleast 1 record with each of the pair (pairA, pairB, pairC, pairD). Each port can be with multiple pairA and i need to compare all of the pairA for that exact port and find out if there is any length changes between 2 records. I need to sort oldest date for that exact pair to newest and then i need to compare all records for it.

Comment: Example - Oldest record for exact port and exact pair compares to second oldest record, then second with third , etc. I have a lot of ports and each of them have many records with pairs(a, b , c, d). Im stuck, because this task is too hard for me. If i could, i would send screenshots .

Answer (score 0):

With `LAG()` window function:

```
select port_nbr, pair, length, add_date, diff
from (
  select *, length - lag(length) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by add_date) diff
 from tablename
) t
where diff > 30
```